# What is the name of the UI component in iOS when you push volume button?

Tags: ios

When you tune the volume with the buttons on the side of the phone, a grey square shows up.
What is it?

This might have been asked, but I don't know which keywords to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Apple don't allow developers access to this UIView.

There is an open source alternative [MPProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) that should help.

Answer (score 0):

[SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) is a better open-source option, and it has already been updated to support iOS7 translucency features.

[image]